# Dispatching multiple actions in redux not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a reducer which is supposed to dispatch multiple actions in redux and is shown as below:

```
const fetchSideBarData = (state, action) => {
    const request = action.sideBarData;
    console.log("KKKK");
    return () => {
        fetchSideBarDataBegin(state);
    };
}
```

where `fetchSideBarDataBegin(state)` is a seperate function. when I use:

```
const fetchSideBarData = (state, action) => {
    const request = action.sideBarData;
    console.log("KKKK");
    return fetchSideBarDataBegin(state);
}
```

it works as expected, but what's wrong with my first syntax which turns my state to undefined.
I want to use the first syntax to pass multiple actions in return statement.

Comment: Reducers are supposed to be pure functions that only consume current state and an action, and return the next state. There should be ***zero*** side-effects like dispatching other actions. The first example you return a function that has a void return, the second you return the result of the function.

Comment: Then how to execute multiple actions within a reducer? I want to turn on a spinner which is in my redux state as isLoading and then turn it off once the process is complete

Comment: Simply, you don't, executing actions isn't the purpose of reducers. Dispatch actions from your UI, or in the case of asynchronous actions (i.e. Thunks) from other actions or epics from rxjs/redux-observables/similar.

Comment: @DrewReese Exactly. Shivam: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/prerequisite-concepts

Comment: @ShivamSahil I would edit your question and include the info from your comment regarding the spinner, look at hooks like useEffect, called with `[]` as second arguement it will only execute once on the inital render

Comment: @iLuvLogix sure, I understood what you guys are pointing out but can you also please give a solution for doing the same?

Comment: @ShivamSahil Maybe you want to have a solid understanding of react and redux (which seems you don't atm) instead of just copy & pasting code  - in that case I strongly suggest you read through the official docs and do some online tutorials as well as play around i.E. stackblitz, but well here we go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-spinner